# Python sys.argv utf-8 to unicode not working

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have the following code which is acting very weirdly.

When I do the following, the utf-8 got converted into unicode nicely.

```
print u'\xE1\x80\x96\xE1\x80\xBB\xE1\x80\xB1\xE1\x80\xAC\xE1\x80\xBA\xE1\x80\x9B\xE1\x80\x8A\xE1\x80\xBA'.encode('raw_unicode_escape')
```

This works fine. However, when I get the utf-8 string from sys.argv, it doesn't work.

```
import sys    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = sys.argv

    input_string = args[1]

    if type(input_string) is not unicode:
        input_string = unicode(input_string, "utf-8")

    print type(input_string)
    print input_string
```

When I run like the following,

```
python test_print.py "\xE1\x80\x96\xE1\x80\xBB\xE1\x80\xB1\xE1\x80\xAC\xE1\x80\xBA\xE1\x80\x9B\xE1\x80\x8A\xE1\x80\xBA"
```

I got the following same string, it doesn't get converted into unicode.

```
<type 'unicode'>
\xE1\x80\x96\xE1\x80\xBB\xE1\x80\xB1\xE1\x80\xAC\xE1\x80\xBA\xE1\x80\x9B\xE1\x80\x8A\xE1\x80\xBA
```

I need to convert the input from sys.argv into unicode chars.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actual Python level string literals (for `str` and `unicode`) are the only place character escapes are parsed by Python automatically. If you want to convert outside strings that use literal escapes like this, you'd do something like this to [explicitly invoke the literal escape interpretation machinery](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings):

```
# Converts from str to str interpreting escapes, then decodes those bytes
# using the UTF-8 encoding
input_string = args[1].decode('string_escape').decode('utf-8')
```

The exact steps are slightly different in Python 3 (you have to use `unicode_escape` and the `codecs` module, and add an extra step to convert the literal decoded `str` to `latin-1` `bytes` before decoding as `utf-8` because text->text encoding and decoding isn't supported), but it's a similar process.

Comment: This is even nicer. Thanks.